# Why aren't my included entities actually included?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2010, with C#.

I have a method used in a repository that returns a object set with various navigation properties included. Up until recently, this method looked like this...

```
private IEnumerable<VRTSystem> GetSystems() {
  return ctx
    .Include(s => s.Customer.CustomerType)
    .Include(s => s.VRTSystemProductConfigurations);
}
```

...where ctx is an ObjectSet of generic type VRTSystem. The full method had a lot more .Include()s than this, but this is enough to show the point.

This worked fine, however I needed to add some code to ensure that only VRTSystemProductConfigurations that had the Active flag set to true were returned. Following the advice commonly given for such situations, I changed the code to look like this...

```
private IEnumerable<VRTSystem> GetSystems() {
  return ctx
    .Include(s => s.Customer.CustomerType)
    .Include(s => s.VRTSystemProductConfigurations)
    .Select(s => new {
      System = s,
      VRTSystemProductConfigurations = s.VRTSystemProductConfigurations.Where(pc => pc.Active)
    })
    .Select(s => s.System);
}
```

However, this new version does not include any of the navigation properties, they are all null.

Anyone any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Entity Framework is not entirely stupid. It sees that in the end only `System`s are queried, so it cuts everything in between and returns `System`s only. And part of the trick you're executing here is to disable lazy loading, so the navigation properties are null and will remain null.

You have to remove the last `Select` out of the scope of the EF query provider by adding an `AsEnumerable`:

```
return ctx
.Include(s => s.Customer.CustomerType)
.Select(s => new {
  System = s,
  VRTSystemProductConfigurations = s.VRTSystemProductConfigurations.Where(pc => pc.Active)
})
.AsEnumerable() 
.Select(s => s.System);
```

And you don't want to include `VRTSystemProductConfigurations`, because that's the collection you want to load partly.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what I did now, but I'm sure I had AsEnumerable() in there at some point whilst trying to fix this. That's part of the normal way to do it. I wonder if I put it in the wrong place? Anyway, I added it as you showed, and it works now, so thanks for that. However, I'm not sure why you think I don't want to include VRTSystemProductConfigurations. Maybe I should have pointed out that we have disabled lazy loading, as these entities are being sent over WCF, so must eagerly include everything. Don't know if that changes things. If not, please explain why you think I should include them.

Comment: It's because you only want to load active `VRTSystemProductConfigurations`, don't you? Wouldn't the Include load all of them?

Comment: Yes, but as have lazy loading switched off, if I didn't use include, then it wouldn't load any of them. As far as I know, this is the only way to do it when you don't use lazy loading.

Comment: The point is that you load the active items separately and EF stitches them together by *relationship fixup*. In the mean time I've found out that the `Include` has no effect. It doesn't load the entire collection, the `Active` predicate is still evaluated.